# Bootstrap 3: Can a nav-pills nav menu collapse like navbar?

Tags: css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I understand that Bootstrap 3 ships with a navbar that collapse when viewed on smaller screens. However, I do not like the look of the navbar and have decided to style my main navigation menu using the `nav-pills` class. Is it possible to collapse my nav-pills menu when viewing it on a phone device? Here's my nav code:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="#"><strong>HOME</strong></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><strong>CAPABILITIES</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><strong>Careers</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><strong>Contracts</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><strong>About Us</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><strong>News</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><strong>Contact us</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a video on Youtube that shows how it is done:
[Bootstrap 3.1 Tutorial 1 - Responsive Grid Layouts By Default!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pB94Fao8iWM)

Basically what Dave does in this video, he makes 2 navigation bars, one with navbar other with nav-pills. Nabvar only visible in xs size, and nav-pills are hidden in xs.

Answer (score 3):

```
<nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills visible-sm visible-xs">
        <li><a href="#"><strong>HOME</strong></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><strong>CAPABILITIES</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><strong>Careers</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><strong>Contracts</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><strong>About Us</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><strong>News</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><strong>Contact us</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Use jquery toggle hide or show feature to make it collapsible.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I ended up just hiding that menu when the screen is for the phone and then using a drop down menu to appear in place of that.